# Is there a wiki server that works from pendrive?

Tags: portable, wiki

I want to do a wiki for documentation of my project, but I develop it in some different places, so I want to have all the information of the wiki on my pendrive.

There is some way to do all the information work on it? Maybe a portable version of the server and the database? Maybe something ready to do this?

Comment: I will try another look at TiddlyWiki, but I'm running MediaWiki from my pen using MoWes

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[TiddlyWiki](http://www.tiddlywiki.com/) would work well.

Answer (score 1):

I use [MoWeS Portable](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Installing_on_MoWeS_Portable_%28Windows%29), it'll set up a webserver, db and mediawiki install all usable from a usb pendrive.

The hyperlink above is for the instructions on the mediawiki site and links to where you download the MoWeS package.

Comment: I got MoWes and worked, but can I add softwares that are not in the list of sofwares of it?

Answer (score 0):

From the portable point of view, I recommend the followings:

- [Ikiwiki](http://ikiwiki.info/)

  - Wiki compiler to generate static HTML so that you can see that anyplace.
- [Juli](http://jjjuli.sourceforge.net/)

  - I developed it for my personal knowledge management.

You may have more detailed situation and requirements so that it would be helpful for us to recommend you to choose a tool.